# Python - writeback function not working

Tags: python, shelve

This is my school project code for a number game: I am trying to store the user's name and score in the database, and then print a list of all user names and scores.

When I run the code the user's name and score is overwritten every time and the previous user and score is not saved.

Shouldn't the **writeback=True** function prevent the data from being overwritten?

```
name=('n')
Fscore=(0)

import shelve

s = shelve.open('hscore_shelf.db',writeback=True)
key1 = [name]
try:
    existing = s['key1']
finally:
    s.close()

print (existing)
import shelve
n = shelve.open('score_shelf.db',writeback=True)
key1 = [Fscore]
try:
    existing = n['key1']
finally:
    s.close()
print(existing)

print("WELCOME TO THE NUMBER QUIZ")
input("HIT ENTER TO START")
name=(input("ENTER YOUR NAME"))
q = (1)
score=(0)
while q <=1 and q >0:

    import random
    num1 =(random.randint(1,9))
    num2 =(random.randint(1,9))
    num3 =(random.randint(1,9))

    index1=num1
    index2=num2
    index3=num3
    e=(" eleven")
    teens=

("ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen")
    units=(" ","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")
    tens=(""," ","twenty ","thirty ","fourty ","fifty ","sixty ","seventy ","eighty ","ninety ")
    hun=("","one hundred and ", "two hundred and ", "three hundred and ", "four hundred and ", "five hundred and ", "six hundred and ", "seven hundred and ", "eight hundred and ", "nine hundred and ")

    print("Type in the following number using digits")
    if num1==0 and num2==0 and num3==0:
        print("zero")
    elif num1==0 and num2==0 and num3>0:
        print(units[index3])
    elif num1==0 and num2==1:
        print(teens[index3])   
    elif num1>0 and num2==1 and num3==1:
        print(hun[index1]+e)
    else:
        print(hun[index1]+tens[index2]+units[index3])

    num11=(int(input("Enter first digit:")))
    num22=(int(input("Enter second digit:")))
    num33=(int(input("Enter third digit:")))

    q = (q-1)
    if num1==num11 and num2==num22 and num3==num33:
        print("Correct")
        score=(score+1)
    else:
        print("Incorrect")


Fscore=(score)
print((name)+" Scored " + str( score))


s = shelve.open('hscore_shelf.db')
try:
    s['key1']=[name]
finally:
    s.close()

n = shelve.open('score_shelf.db')
try:
    n['key1']=[Fscore]
finally:
    n.close()
```

Comment: You don't need to import shelve twice

Comment: `s['key1']=[name]` Perhaps it's because you're using the literal string `'key1'` as the key, and thus you're overwriting the same key every time, instead of using the value of the key1 variable as the key?

Comment: Also, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve.open) says `If the optional writeback parameter is set to True, all entries accessed are also cached in memory`

Comment: I have changed the code so now there is only one database, and so key1 = [name] is now name = [Fscore]. It has come up with the following error. value = self.cache[key] TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' –

Comment: also, this error is from the line; existing = s[name] i can post the updated code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: You don't need to `import shelve` twice.

What shelve does is store a "dictionary-like" object in python. When you reassign the 'key1' key to a different value, you're essentially overwriting it. Instead, try using only one db instead, have the "name" be a key, and "score" be a value.

Comment: I have changed the code so now there is only one database, and so  key1 = [name] is now name = [Fscore]. It has come up with the following error. value = self.cache[key]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Why are you setting the value equal to a list? should most likely be `s[name] = Fscore` (no bracket on the right side).

Comment: I have tried    s[name] = Fscore    and the user name and score are still being overwritten?

Comment: Are you adding different names? It will overwrite the same name here